# Android: restore MenuItem ActionView after Fragment switch

Tags: android, android-animation, menuitem

In my FragmentActivity I create an a MenuItem that has to perform a clockwise animation in actionBar when user click it and stop when an AsyncTask has finished. This is the code I use when I start and stop the refresh:

```
public void completeRefresh(MenuItem menuItem) {
     if(menuItem!=null){
         if(menuItem.getActionView()!=null){
             menuItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
             menuItem.setActionView(null);
         }
     }
 }

 public void refresh(MenuItem menuItem) {
     /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_action_view, null);

     Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clockwise_refresh);
     rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     iv.startAnimation(rotation);

     menuItem.setActionView(iv);
 }
```

This works great but I have a problem when i switch fragment. The Activity consists in a ViewPager that contains two fragments. When i switch fragment while the ActionView with animation is in progress, in the new Fragment I see the two clockwise MenuItems, one animating up the other. And the animation never finish.
This is a screenshot of the problem. How can I avoid that? [image: When I switch Fragment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two independent `Fragments` doing *stuff* and one common `ActionBar` to show a state.

In your case, it would be best to not manage the state of the `ActionBar` from within the Fragments themselves but rather from the `FragmentActivity`. The `FragmentActivity` hosts your `ViewPager` (and Fragments). Depending on the state of the `ViewPager` and its Fragments, use callbacks to notify the `FragmentActivity` to change the state of the `ActionBar`.

For example (PSEUDO):

```
   onViewPagerPageChanged(..){
       refreshActionBar();
   }

   onButtonClickedInFragment1(..){
       ... //do again something with the ActionBar but don't let the Fragment be the owner
   }
```

And don't forget to invalidate the ActionBar after adding/removing/editing items

```
   getActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved simply removing setHasOptionMenu(true) from my Fragments.

Comment: But then the fragments can't have menuitems?